# Keep first and last rows of repetitive columns values of a panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1    col2    col3 
 1        A       P
 2        B       P
 3        C       P
 4        D       P
 5        E       Q
 6        F       Q
 7        G       Q
 8        H       P
 9        I       P
 10       J       P
 11       K       P
```

I want to create a new data frame from above with following condition,
If col3 values are same, just keep the first and last rows of repetitive col3 values.

so the final data frame will look like,

```
df
col1    col2    col3 
 1        A       P
 4        D       P
 5        E       Q
 7        G       Q
 8        H       P
 11       K       P
```

I could do this using a for loop and iterating with the next rows, but using it the execution time will be more. Looking for some pandas shortcuts/ pythonic way to do this task most efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try `shift` and `cusmum` create the group , then we do `duplicated`

```
s=df.col3.shift().ne(df.col3).cumsum()
sdf=df[~(s.duplicated() & s.iloc[::-1].duplicated())].copy()
sdf
Out[219]: 
    col1 col2 col3
0      1    A    P
3      4    D    P
4      5    E    Q
6      7    G    Q
7      8    H    P
10    11    K    P
```

Comment: it's a great answer without using groupby. I think about the solution using `groupby.nth`, but yours is better :) +1

Answer (score 0):

the [nth](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#taking-the-nth-row-of-each-group) method for groupby works as well, as @Andy.L suggested :

```
#get cumulative on col3
df['col4'] = df.col3.ne(df.col3.shift()).cumsum()
df.groupby('col4',sort=False).nth([0,-1])

         col1 col2 col3
col4            
1           1   A   P
1           4   D   P
2           5   E   Q
2           7   G   Q
3           8   H   P
3           11  K   P
```